# Why isn't {a: never} equivalent to never?

Tags: typescript

It seems like `{a: never}` should be able to be simplified to `never`. Doing so would fix my issues below. Is there a reason this isn't possible?

```
type A = {tag: 'A', value: number}
type B = {tag: 'B', value: boolean}
type N = {tag: never, value: string}

type Ntag = N["tag"] // never
type Nvalue = N["value"] // string
// Couldn't N["value"] be simplified to never because an object of type N could never exist?
// And thus, couldn't N be simplified to never?

type AN = A | N
type ANtag = AN["tag"] // "A"
type ANvalue = AN["value"] // Expected: number, Actual: string | number
// AN has to be an A, an object of type N can't exist. So why can't AN["value"] be simplified to number?

type AB = A | B
type NarrowToA = AB & {tag: 'A'} // Expected A, Actual: (A & {tag: "A"}) | (B & {tag: "A"})
type NarrowToATag = NarrowToA["tag"] // A
type NarrowToAValue = NarrowToA["value"] // Expected number, Actual number | boolean
// Again, NarrowToA has to be an A, an object of type B would never fit. So why can't NarrowToA["value"] be simplified to number?
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDewCGBzAXFA5DHANFAG6oA2ArhNgHYUC2ARhAE4C+AUKJFAEILI0WXL0IlyVbIwD20shFQ1O3aADkBKDLQjFWRUpWpQAzsBYBLGuk5dwaoQNUBtAERCXAXSgB6b1Bo6rLY8qgZUjq5hEJ4+fqYWVhy+UADC0hRkACY0OMBQzi5RMcwm5vRgZOYAZuYQmVDA0v6BLFDMAMaoFMbQilDSjABWEO150lUNdvlQ7elZzbqtEAAe5qYA-El+MDT1wAAW3USzGdm50yXGZRXVtXtNAYubwdAw6ohwAD75L7CqDh8Cu4vMkXDAXL83lEBG9IhJoiC-ABRZaQUZ1WgMZgsIgwUYUcjYeKWdBQb50JhBZJvKD7VDGBpNEp9GBEPoDYajfoTFTTTo5PIrNbAAB0UAAyk0AO77EAzRTnWGFeHFaBXcqVGp1Rn+LGsZ68mD8D5kvi-VSoFgsaRSgAq0jgH34ADJBFpcPg2LEoCi0cBtazYPjCVAABRwV2aYRglxsACUptDLrd0fB8fNlutdodtowjkzNvtMFcwO9MAzVsLDoAavD85Xs8XlYYYslfSN-fUKdjccGyLrKa1vjI5AoaFtYOhUJYiBaG0XafSdcyaLA2auOR3uZMePwpXMuy0oDVRRLpbL5QL8gXG3CW15LtdNXcdd39UA)

Comment: `{a: never}` would fail type check as long as you access `a`. Otherwise - if `never` does not happen - it's not a problem.

Comment: @zerkms interesting. Could you provide an example of how that might look in code? What would a valid value of type `{a: never}` even look like?

Comment: You cannot create a value of that type, because you cannot assign to its required property `a`. But you can use that type.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your comment @zerkms! It made me realize that the following is a valid value of type `N`. So it is possible for an object to exist that has a property of type `never`.

```
type N = {tag: never, value: string}

const n: N = {
    get tag(): never {
        while (true) {}
    },

    value: 'hi'
}

const nTag = n.tag; // Type: never
const nValue = n.value; // Type: string
```